# Execute multiple mysql updates in one query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

What is the best way to merge two mysqli query's as one query

TABLE SERVER_JOINS

```
ID    DEFAULT   SERVER_ID     MEMBER_ID
---------------------------------------
1       0         1             57
2       0         52            57
3       0         22            57
4       1         35            57
```

Only one row must have default as 1
By clicking on a link i want to change the default value

```
mysqli_query($database->connection,"UPDATE `server_joins` SET 
`default` = '0' WHERE `default` = '1' AND `member_id` = '$session->u_id'");

mysqli_query($database->connection,"UPDATE `server_joins` SET 
`default` = '1' WHERE `server_id`= '$id' AND `member_id` = '$session->u_id'");
```

Comment: You don't need to run first query, cause second one will do the same.

Comment: i have multiple rows. Only one row must have a default value as 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to schieve something like that:

```
mysqli_query($database->connection,"UPDATE `server_joins` 
SET `default` = '1' 
WHERE `default`= '0' AND `server_id`= '$id' AND `member_id` = '$session->u_id'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `if()` function or a conditional `case` expression in the `set` clause depending on the value of the server field to decide whether default is to be set to 0 or 1.

```
UPDATE `server_joins`
SET `default` = if(`server_id`= $id, 1, 0)
WHERE `member_id` = $session->u_id
```

Couple of notes:

1. Your code is likely to be vulnerable to sql injection attack. Consider using prepared statements with parameters.
2. If you have numeric values in a field, then do not pass the values as string. Mysql has to convert the values on the flight.

Comment: i use $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,(int)$_GET['default_server']);

Comment: Fair enough. What about the main part of the answer?